# c# sort XElement, with comments

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, linq-to-xml

I have an XElement that represents following xml:

```
<Node>
 <Child id="1" /><!-- Comment 1 -->
 <Child id="3" /><!-- Comment 3 -->
 <Child id="2" /><!-- Comment 2 -->
</Node>
```

How can I sort the children of Node so that the XElement.ToString() method returns the following?
The comments and text behind the child must be moved along.

```
<Node>
 <Child id="1" /><!-- Comment 1 -->
 <Child id="2" /><!-- Comment 2 -->
 <Child id="3" /><!-- Comment 3 -->
</Node>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each element is succeeded by the corresponding comment, try the following:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(/* your xml */);
var reordered = xDoc.Root
                    .Elements("Child")
                    .Select(el => new {
                                        Element = el,
                                        Comments = el.NodesAfterSelf()
                                                     .TakeWhile(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment)
                                      })
                    .OrderBy(pair => (int)pair.Element.Attribute("id"))
                    .SelectMany(pair => new [] { pair.Element }.Concat(pair.Comments));
xDoc.Root.ReplaceAll(reordered);
```

**EDIT**: edited to allow any (incl. 0) number of comments per element; whitespace was already handled.

Comment: It's possible that there is whitespace between the element and comment. It's also possible that there are multiple comments.

Comment: @TWT - updated my answer to allow multiple (or 0) comments, whitespace was not an issue even for the previous version.

Comment: One important remark I want to add here is that all comments before the first node will be removed.

Comment: @TWT - which is absolutely true; however - you haven't mentioned those in your problem description. Moreover - there doesn't seem to be any default way to sort them - if you'll expand on your original question, I'll try to help.